# Warning banner for all incoming external emails in zimbra

Tags: zimbra

I am looking for a solution, where we can add a notification/warning banner in the incoming external email body like below in zimbra.

```
"[EXTERNAL EMAIL] This email has been received from an external source – please review before any action, clicking on links, or opening attachments."
```

Does Zimbra offer any method of creating a warning banner for all incoming external email messages or are there any methods to do such a thing?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

See the blog post here for the steps : [How to Add External Email Warning Message](https://imanudin.net/2020/10/17/zimbra-tips-how-to-add-external-email-warning-message/)

Be sure to follow the steps under the "Update 2 Dec 2020" heading to add your local domain as an exception. Otherwise the warnings will be added to your local e-mails as well.

I also suggest to rather add the warnings as a footer at the bottom of e-mails instead of pretext at the top of e-mails. The reason is that the pretext does not always work when the e-mail is a MIME multipart message, so it might be that the warning is not displayed on some external e-mails, eg. coming from Gmail. Footers always works. To display it as a footer, just change the --pretext and --pretext-html to --disclaimer and --disclaimer-html, like this:

```
use strict;

$altermime='/opt/zimbra/common/bin/altermime';
@altermime_args_disclaimer = qw(--verbose --disclaimer=/opt/zimbra/data/altermime/_OPTION_.txt --disclaimer-html=/opt/zimbra/data/altermime/_OPTION_.html --force-for-bad-html);
$defang_maps_by_ccat{+CC_CATCHALL} = ['disclaimer'];
$allow_disclaimers = 1;
@local_domains_maps = (["."]);
@disclaimer_options_bysender_maps = ({
        'yourdomain.com' => 'local_domains',
        '.' => 'external_domains',

},);

1;
```